# Removing Non-English Words From Corpus

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have the raw content (text and HTML markup) from thousands of websites. The end goal is exploring [topic modeling](https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python/blob/master/07-working-with-text-data.ipynb) and [clustering](https://github.com/brandomr/document_cluster/blob/master/cluster_analysis_web.ipynb). There are many examples of how to filter out non-English words using Python, but unfortunately most do not quite work for the corpus with which I'm working. A few reasons why:

- No geographic info is included in the data set, so cannot just filter by [English-speaking countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_entities_where_English_is_an_official_language)
- Even if some geographic data can be inferred (.e.g, a `.in` top-level domain), there is still the possibility the document extracted from that site will contain English

Here's why the following posts don't quite work in my case:

[In python, extracting non-English words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790234/in-python-extracting-non-english-words) was a good start, especially because it also removed punctuation, but it still includes non-English words:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

In  [1]: test_str = Series(['中', 'hello','زندگی','Yo!','かたて く範囲','+44 designer','{{appDetails.title}} {{"TERM','The Pen Company ✒',np.nan,' Shopping Cart:0 Log In/Register'])

In  [2]: test_str.str.findall('[^\W]+')
Out [2]:
0                                       [中]
1                                   [hello]
2                                   [زندگی]
3                                      [Yo]
4                                [かたて, く範囲]
5                            [44, designer]
6                 [appDetails, title, TERM]
7                       [The, Pen, Company]
8                                       NaN
9    [Shopping, Cart, 0, Log, In, Register]
dtype: object
```

[Extract non-content English language words string - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904678/extract-non-content-english-language-words-string-python) is more about using stop-words, which I am already planning on using, for example:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
english_stops = stopwords.words('english')
vect = CountVectorizer(max_features=10000,max_df=.2,stop_words=english_stops)
```

One possibility here though...the Python NLTK shows an example of creating a [list of all English-language words](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html#regular-expressions-for-detecting-word-patterns):

```
wordlist = [w for w in nltk.corpus.words.words('en') if w.islower()]
```

which could then be used to filter tokens...however, given the amount of data that seems like a sub-optimal option. Similar approaches would be [Removing non-english words from a sentence in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031556/removing-non-english-words-from-a-sentence-in-python) or [dropping row containing non-english words in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866196/dropping-row-containing-non-english-words-in-pandas-dataframe), but again, using English dictionaries to match word-by-word seems excessive.

An example function from a [notebook demonstrating clustering](https://github.com/brandomr/document_cluster/blob/master/cluster_analysis_web.ipynb) also lets through non-English languages.

```
def tokenize_only(text):
    # first tokenize by sentence, then by word to ensure that punctuation is caught as it's own token
    tokens = [word.lower() for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(text) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent)]
    filtered_tokens = []
    # filter out any tokens not containing letters (e.g., numeric tokens, raw punctuation)
    for token in tokens:
        if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', token):
            filtered_tokens.append(token)
    return filtered_tokens
```

In this case, Finnish words like `Etusivu` will pass through the filters.

Ideally, any solutions will not take an approach of checking each word in the corpus; that being said, I'm open to whatever path others with more experience have taken (including a word-by-word check) :-)

Comment: Have you tried getting a **huge** dictionary of English words and just comparing each element in your arrays to that body of text? I'm talking millions and millions of words' worth of the English language. With a large enough dictionary, you would be able to capture most of the English words in your corpus, and less informative (read: rarely-occurring) words would probably be left out, as they normally should be in text mining.

Comment: I have not done that yet--there are a few links above that show how to potentially do that, however, I wanted to see if anyone had a method other than checking token-by-token.

Comment: @measureallthethings, do you want to remove single non-english words or complete sentences (if they have non-english words)?

Comment: @MaxU remove single non-english words...which is a good point...feel like i may have to do token-by-token check

Comment: @measureallthethings Yeah, it's going to be slow (at scale) if you have a bunch of `list` objects instead of `set`s. And you usually don't want to use sets when doing something like topic modeling. Checking whether an element is in a set is O(1), but doing so for each word in your corpus is O(n).

Comment: @not_a_robot, yeah, i just checked it `words = set([w.lower() for w in nltk.corpus.words.words('en')]); %timeit 'word' in words` gives me: `10000000 loops, best of 3: 176 ns per loop` ;-)

Comment: there is one problem in this approach though - what are you going to do with words wich are written the same in different languages?

Comment: @MaxU, hah, haven't thought of that...do you have a quick example? i may need to read up on how prevalent that is

Comment: @measureallthethings, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_orthographically_identical_words_in_English_and_Spanish

Comment: @MaxU ah, ok. then definitely worth addressing. thanks!

Comment: @measureallthethings, it's going to be a tough fight: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_English_words_by_country_or_language_of_origin

Comment: For posterity's sake, a colleague suggested this to me: https://github.com/Mimino666/langdetect. Haven't implemented fully, but shows promise. One example from the documentation: `>>> detect("War doesn't show who's right, just who's left.")
'en'`

Comment: You need to run a proper word level language ID. It's not hard to build one.

Comment: Any solution for this? I was also matching word-by-word to eliminate non-English words in my corpus, it takes years to finish tho.

Comment: Any specific reason for only selecting only lower case words for the wordlist?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, I'll encourage you to ask the question here in the discussion instead https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions. Most probably the questions would be flagged as "asking for tool/fix recommendation" as it is now.